# Animating Draw Programmatically

Tags: android, paint, draw

My app teaches how to write letters and I want to draw for example letter "A" programmatically.

I do not want to draw it pixel by pixel(it is so hard!)

What other ways to do that?

**UPDATE**:
I want to show how to write "A" not just showing A in the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Canvas, you can draw text on canvas using this:

```
canvas.drawText("A",marginFromLeft,MarginFromRight, paint);
```

also you can draw bitmap of A on canvas using this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,marginLeft,marginTop, paint);
```

after drawing this,you can animate an other image like circle using animationSet:

```
anim One:   animate circle moving from bottom left to top center of A
anim Two:   animate circle moving from top center of A to bottom left Right
anim Three: animate circle moving from left-verticaly-center to right-verticaly-center.
```

Comment: I want to show how to write "A" not just showing A in the screen

Comment: i updated my answer with solution i usually saw on other education related apps.!

Comment: thanks,so i should make formula for each of 3 move with animationset?

Comment: yes,you got me! also if this answer solved your question than mark this as answer by clicking on tick mark,for others help.

Comment: i found http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2012/01/curved-motion-in-android.html that can do my work easier but i have problem in it to change to solve my problem(i asked in another question),if solved i will post that here

Comment: finally i decided to make gif animations of tracing alphabet and play it in my app

Answer (score 2):

Romain Guy recently wrote a blog post on how to do path tracing using paths. If you can construct paths yourself (or finding a method for creating correct paths for letters) you could use the information from his blog to do something.

http://www.curious-creature.org/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/#more-1904

Good luck